# Не работает форма входа

Tags: php, javascript, form, auth

Почему пишет что пароль неверный. Пароль успешно шифруется и хранится в базе, но функция `password_verify` не работает? Вот содержание `login.php`:

```
    <?php
    $data['error_message'] = $lang['error_empty_login'];

    $loginId = $escapeObj->stringEscape($_POST['login_id']);
    $hash = password_hash($_POST['login_password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $crypto_pass = password_verify($_POST['login_password'], $hash);

    $userId = getUserId($conn, $loginId);

    if ($userId)
    {
    $query = $conn->query("SELECT id,username,email_verified FROM " . DB_ACCOUNTS . " WHERE id=$userId AND password='$crypto_pass' AND type='user' AND active=1");
    $data['error_message'] = $lang['error_bad_login'];

    if ($query->num_rows == 1)
    {
    $fetch = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $continue = true;

    if ($config['email_verification'] == 1 && $fetch['email_verified'] == 0)
    {
        $continue = false;
        $data['error_message'] = $lang['error_verify_email'];
    }

    if ($continue == true)
    {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $fetch['id'];
        $_SESSION['user_pass'] = $crypto_pass;

        if (isset($_POST['keep_logged_in']) && $_POST['keep_logged_in'] == true)
        {
            setcookie('sk_u_i', $_SESSION['user_id'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
            setcookie('sk_u_p', $_SESSION['user_pass'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
        }

        $data['status'] = 200;
        $data['redirect_url'] = smoothLink('index.php?tab1=home');
    }
   }
     else
{
    $data['error_message'] = $lang['incorrect_password'];
}
    }
    else
   {
$data['error_message'] = $lang['no_user_found'];
    }

    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    echo json_encode($data);
    $conn->close();
    exit();
```

Comment: ужасный код....

Comment: версия php какая?

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял, переменная $crypto_pass выведет 0 или 1 (false/true), а не сам пароль, так что при селекте в БД, нужно использовать:

```
SELECT id,username,email_verified FROM " . DB_ACCOUNTS . " WHERE id=$userId AND password='**$hash**'
```

Comment: $_SESSION['user_pass'] = $crypto_pass;
Здесь тоже замени на $hash

Comment: $hash - это захешированный пароль, а $crypto_pass - переменная, отвечающая за проверку введенного пароля и пароля из базы.

Comment: Ты из моего кода (**$hash**) убрал звездочки, которые находятся до и после переменной $hash

Comment: Какую ошибку-то пишет? Неверный пароль?

Comment: @danilabodrov навсякий случай, захешируй пароль самостоятельно, занеси этот пароль в БД и проверь ещё раз вход.